# Performing String Methods on Object Properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object

Whenever I try to perform string operations on variables that contain the values of object's properties in Javascript, I get an error about the interpreter not being able to find whatever the method Im trying to use for that object:

```
var arrOfEntries = {};

arrOfEntries["name1"] = "Jane" ;
arrOfEntries["age1"] = "40" ;
arrOfEntries["name2"] = "Kathy" ;
arrOfEntries["age2"] = "35" ;
arrOfEntries["name3"] = "Mary" ;
arrOfEntries["age3"] = "23" ;
arrOfEntries["name4"] = "Donna" ;
arrOfEntries["age4"] = "32" ;

var result = ' ';
for (prop in arrOfEntries) {
    var tempVar = String(prop) /*/this line was added as an attempt to force the property into the type String, but does not work*
    if (tempVar.includes("name"))
        result += tempVar
    }
```

In this case, I simply wish to check for the existence of the string "name" within the name of each property of that object and then collect only these properties for further actions. What am I missing here?

Comment: @dave type `String(5)` into your console

Comment: I erroneously mentioned that I was trying to check for "name" within the property's value, but I meant to say that I want to filter all properties names for the string "name", not the values......

Comment: The object properties are already strings, there's no need to force it. `includes` is an ES7 proposed Array function, so I doubt your browser supports it. Use `indexOf("name") === -1` to see if the property includes "name"

Comment: In addition to other suggestions, which browser/version are you using? `includes` is a relatively new method.

Comment: `arrOfEntries ` is an object, not an array. It looks like your following the terrible naming convention of prepending variable names with their 'type'. So intThis, strThat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prop` is already a string. You should just need this:

```
for (prop in arrOfEntries) {
    if (arrOfEntries.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop.indexOf("name") !== -1) {
        result += arrOfEntries[prop];
    }
}
```

I added `hasOwnProperty` so that you wouldn't erroneously try and add a method that already exists on the `Object` type.

Also just FYI: `arrOfEntries` is an object (with string/value keys), not an array - there is some distinction in JavaScript types.

Comment: If you used `Object.keys` and iterate over them there would be no need for the `hasOwnProperty` check. Just FYI, still a good answer.

Comment: Your answer and Sterling Archer's were most helpful to me. I was able to simply incorporate "prop.indexOf("name") > -1" and it worked as I expected!

Comment: Also, I totally understand that arrOfEntries is not actually an array but an object. That name is helpful to me though, still, because I am logically treating this object like an array of the associative type......I did have to learn that the hard way though......thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `largerString.indexOf("substring")`, as `includes()` does not have wide browser support.

The `indexOf()` method will tell you the starting position (as an integer) of the first match of `substring` within `largerString`. If no matches were found, it returns `-1`

See below:

```
var arrOfEntries = {};

arrOfEntries["name1"] = "Jane" ;
arrOfEntries["age1"] = "40" ;
arrOfEntries["name2"] = "Kathy" ;
arrOfEntries["age2"] = "35" ;
arrOfEntries["name3"] = "Mary" ;
arrOfEntries["age3"] = "23" ;
arrOfEntries["name4"] = "Donna" ;
arrOfEntries["age4"] = "32" ;

var result = ' ';
for (prop in arrOfEntries) {
    if (prop.indexOf("name") >= 0) {
        result += prop
    }
}
```

If you do a `console.log(result)` you will get `"name1name2name3name4"`

Answer (score 0):

Do sth like that:

```
var arrOfEntries = {};
arrOfEntries["name1"] = "Jane" ; arrOfEntries["age1"] = "40" ;
arrOfEntries["name2"] = "Kathy" ; arrOfEntries["age2"] = "35" ;
arrOfEntries["name3"] = "Mary" ; arrOfEntries["age3"] = "23" ;
arrOfEntries["name4"] = "Donna" ; arrOfEntries["age4"] = "32" ;
var result = ' ';
for (prop in arrOfEntries) {
if (prop.indexOf('name') != -1)
{
 alert(arrOfEntries[prop]);
}
}
```

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues:

1. You're trying to force the value into a string by using `var tempVar = String(prop)` which isn't going to work because you left out the `new` operator. It should be `var tempVar = new String(prop);`. You can ignore it though since it's not needed.
2. `String.prototype.includes` was introduced in ES6 and doesn't have wide browser support yet. Check the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes for more details.
3. Considering the lack of support for `includes`, you can use `indexOf` as a replacement: `if (prop.indexOf('name') >= 0) { // 'name' is included }`